# Spring boot: How should I deploy my microservices

Tags: spring-boot, docker, nginx, microservices, infrastructure

So at first I built a simple monolith application and deploy it using docker and nginx (for reverse proxy only). for now I have plan to separate each services because some services require a lot of time and IO to do their jobs. I have researched about it and I know some components that I'll need like spring cloud eureka, service discovery and etc. I'm a bit confused because I only use docker and nginx if I add these components do I still need nginx on top it? can you give me an example of structure that I should know or apply to my project.

Comment: I think Nginx proxy could be useful for external traffic eq. client's browser -> your app. Nginx can handle SSL certificates. but if two services communicate internally then the connection should be direct  (without Nginx)

Answer (score 1):

In your first iteration of the refactoring you can do without Service Discovery:

- create a SpringBoot app for each microservice
- services talk to each other directly (no need to have Nginx), also without Service Discovery it means that you hardcode (or store in a property file) the URL of the endpoints
- deploy NGINX in front of the application/service which serves the end users (ie a Web Application)

Once you have validated your new architecture (splitting the responsibilities across the microservices) you can introduce Service Discovery (Eureka) so the endpoints are no longer hardcoded.

Nginx is pretty light so it can also be used for handling internal traffic if you like, but at this point you architecture should start considering volume of traffic and number of components to decide what works better.

Comment: Should I deploy each service on the different server or can I just deploy it on the same server using docker container.

Comment: You can use one server running multiple Docker containers (each one is a service), I assume you are still developing/testing the architecture. On a PROD system yes you would want to deploy services on different nodes, etc... but when you get there you need to consider if using another layer (Kubernetes, Swarm)